# Signing android application issue with google+ keyhash

Tags: android, hash, google-plus

So in order to release my android application, I used Android Studio to create my keysotre `myAppName.jks`. Throughtout the development proccess, I was using the `debug.keystore` in order to test my application with Google+ api and it was working fine. I created a new google api project and I used this line of code in my terminal to get my SHA1 KeyHash:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias myAppName -keystore "C://path to my myAppName.jks" -list -v
```

Then it asks me for a password, I entred my password and got the SHA1 keyhash.

I entered the Sha1 key in my newly created app. I ran my application on my phone, and the app immediately crashes. I tried reversing back to my debug.keystore sha1 key and the app worked fine. So I know the problem is caused by the new sha1 keyhash. How can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you run signed apk on your device with yoour original keystore.

Comment: @HareshChhelana could you elaborate more? the original keystore is the default debug key. Yes, I have ran application multiple time with while developing.

Comment: You have to make signed apk using your myAppName.jks keystore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I left my work and went to do something else. I came back one day later and everything was working perfectly.